# Excel macro taking longtime

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below excel which takes longtime to complete.

Usually i will have 30k records in invoice sheet and GRN sheet.

Can anyone suggest me to complete this task in faster way?

```
Sub CheckReturn()
Dim LastInvRow As Long
Dim LastGRNRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Application.Calculation = xlManual

LastInvRow = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastGRNRow = Sheets("GRN").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastInvRow
  For j = 2 To LastGRNRow
    If Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 11).Value = "Customer Return" And _
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 3).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 7).Value And _
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 18).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 19).Value Then
      
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 34).Copy
       Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 48).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 35).Copy
       Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 49).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 36).Copy
       Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 50).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      Exit For
    End If
  Next j
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

MsgBox "Completed - " & Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: Research how to use arrays instead of accessing cell values directly. Read data into arrays, work your data and write the array back to your cells. This is usually much faster than working with cells directly. Also if you have to work with cells directly avoid copy/paste if you want to copy a value only use  `Cells(row, col).Value = Cells(row, col).Value`.

Comment: Note that if you have 30k rows in both sheets this means 900 Mio iterations of your nested loops. This will run forever. If each iteration only takes 0.001 seconds this means a runtime of 10.4 days! • Re-think your approach.

Comment: If you're going to loop through sheets with that many rows I'd strongly suggest setting `ScreenUpdating` and `EnableEvents` to `False` on top the `Calculation` to manual which you already have. As already stated as well use `value = value` instead of `Copy/Paste` when you just want the values.

Answer (score 0):

This one should be a bit faster. Because you don´t get the values of a and b each time when the for j loop begins.

```
Sub CheckReturn()
Dim LastInvRow As Long
Dim LastGRNRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Application.Calculation = xlManual

LastInvRow = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastGRNRow = Sheets("GRN").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastInvRow
  a=Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 7).Value
  b=Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 19).Value
  c=Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 34).Value
  d=Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 35).Value
  e=Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 36).Value
  For j = 2 To LastGRNRow
    If Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 11).Value = "Customer Return" And _
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 3).Value = a And _
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 18).Value = b Then
      
       Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 48).Value=c
       Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 49).Value=d
       Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 50).Value=e
       Application.Statusbar= i*j*100/LastInvRow*LastGRNRow & "%"
      Exit For
    End If
  Next j
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

MsgBox "Completed - " & Now()
End Sub
```

The statusbar will show you the progress of your task in %.

Comment: Still, even if one iteration is only 0.0001 seconds it will run longer than one day. This won't fix the main problem of this code. Even 0.00001 seconds take 2.5 hours.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ for sure, thats not what i mean, his approach of a solution may be not the right, but i wanted to help him. Maybe he knows how long it will run and wants to reduce from 10 days to 1-2 days. It also could be that he meant that there are 30k entries in both sheets combined.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do direct transfer of data from one sheet to the other and turn off some applications to make it even fater. Try this one:

```
Sub CheckReturn()

Dim LastInvRow As Long
Dim LastGRNRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'turn applications off, to make the macro go faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Application.Calculation = xlManual

LastInvRow = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastGRNRow = Sheets("GRN").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To LastInvRow
  For j = 2 To LastGRNRow
  
    If Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 11).Value = "Customer Return" And _
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 3).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 7).Value And _
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 18).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 19).Value Then
      
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 34).Copy = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 48)
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 35).Copy = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 49)
       Sheets("GRN").Cells(j, 36) = Sheets("Invoice").Cells(i, 50)
       
      Exit For
    End If
  Next j
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

MsgBox "Completed - " & Now()

'turn applications back on..
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Still, even if one iteration is only 0.0001 seconds it will run longer than one day. This won't fix the main problem of this code. Even 0.00001 seconds take 2.5 hours.